# Enforce front-end validation of email field in PlayFramework 2.6 with Bootstrap 4

Tags: scala, validation, bootstrap-4, playframework-2.6

So I've got my simple form defined as:

```
val loginForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email" -> email,
    "password" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 8, maxLength = 24)
  )(UserLogin.apply)(UserLogin.unapply)
)
```

My view:

```
@b4.inline.form(routes.UserController.loginPage()) { implicit ifc =>
  @b4.email( form("email"), '_hiddenLabel -> "Email", 'placeholder -> "your email address")
  @b4.password( form("password"), '_hiddenLabel -> "Password", 'placeholder -> "your password")
  @b4.submit('class -> "btn btn-light btn-outline-dark"){ Login }
}
```

Obviously my password field is validated in front-end, but not the email.
Is there a canonical way to enforce email being required during front-end validation?

Comment: what do you mean by it's not validated?

Comment: It wasn't check at all, but *required* is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is validated on frontend, but only if it is not empty.

You need to mark the field explicitly as "required":

```
@b4.email( form("email"), '_hiddenLabel -> "Email", 'placeholder -> "your email address", 'required -> true)
```